# How to store sensitive string data - Android development

Tags: android

I have included few strings in my code. I want to hide those strings from external hackers.

Can anybody plz help me...

Comment: Could you explain the question in detail.

Comment: I am using constant strings in my code.. If I use dextojar converter to extract source from my apk file I can see all my code with constant strings.. It means hacker can easily acquire my string constats.. I don't want to expose my string constants ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AES encryption to encrypt/decrypt your data and store/read it from file or shared preferences. The AES key can be hardcoded in the app, or you can use random generated key which will be stored at different place.

Comment: Thanks peceps, I got it you helped me to pick up right encryption method.. Thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

I think **Proguard** gives security to your code (**obfustication**). If you want additional security you have to use **Encryption**. then separately you can **encrpt** the string and store in a file. whenever you want to use the data you have to read the file **decrypt** the data.

Comment: Obfuscation isn't security. "There is no security through obscurity".

Comment: You said "I think Proguard gives security to your code (obfustication)." Obfuscation isn't security.

Comment: I am using Proguard in my code but it doesn't actually change the constant string.. It works in case of method name, variable names but not for string constats..

Comment: Thanks for the help guys... I am planning to use encryption in my code  I hope it will solve the problem... Thanks again...